# Kali Linux under Xen

Tags: xen

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg0
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  19
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               465.76 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119234
  Alloc PE / Size       27904 / 109.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       91330 / 356.76 GiB
  VG UUID               M4aiqh-Qe9d-2NmV-AtN1-gclm-zM5S-Wz7lGB




kernel      = '/vmlinuz'
ramdisk     = '/initrd.img'
vcpus       = '2'
memory      = '1024'
root        = '/dev/xvda1 ro'
disk        = [ 'phy:/dev/vg0/kali,xvda1,w', 'file:/tmp/kali-linux-mini-2016.1-amd64.iso,hdc:cdrom,r']
name        = 'kali'
dhcp        = 'dhcp'
vif         = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]



[    1.332510] blkfront: xvda1: flush diskcache: enabled
[    1.338310] blkfront: xvdc: flush diskcache: enabled
[    1.338923]  xvdc: xvdc1 xvdc2
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... modprobe: can't load module xen-pciback (kernel/drivers/xen/xen-pciback/xen-pciback.ko): No such device
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... [    1.499945] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.500047] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
done.
Begin: Waiting for root file system ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
modprobe: module unknown not found in modules.dep
mount: mounting /dev/xvda1 on /root failed: No such file or directory
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
done.
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
modprobe: module ehci-pci not found in modules.dep
modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep
[   35.567532] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[   35.567556] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[   35.567600] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[   35.567988] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[   35.569760] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[   35.571497] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[   35.573923] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   35.573928] usbhid: USB HID core driver


BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
(initramfs)



kernel      = '/vmlinuz'
ramdisk     = '/initrd.img'
vcpus       = '2'
memory      = '4096'
root        = '/dev/xvda1 ro'
disk        = [ 'phy:/dev/vg0/domU-test-disk,xvda1,w', 'file:/tmp/debian-8.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso,hdc:cdrom,r']
name        = 'domU-test'
dhcp        = 'dhcp'
vif         = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/domU-test-disk
  LV Name                domU-test-disk
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                LAjXbD-I9PO-mcTz-bAS3-zEIn-zCvp-0SVP35
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time station, 2015-12-02 00:55:35 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                20.00 GiB
  Current LE             5120
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/xen-win7
  LV Name                xen-win7
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                fS4l8p-pkdD-5ObZ-E4T6-rlmj-xF3d-eFzXGn
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time station, 2015-12-05 04:48:22 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/freebsd
  LV Name                freebsd
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                O8V2VW-UGNM-bzyY-UIcW-719D-ek02-eptZDA
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time station, 2015-12-06 01:45:36 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                19.00 GiB
  Current LE             4864
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/kali
  LV Name                kali
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                8ZlyUg-WT2C-XiJA-dRrU-NQfM-axPi-l1YMS5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time station, 2016-02-27 13:52:14 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                20.00 GiB
  Current LE             5120
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you. One thing that changes is that within the kali machine, the disk isn't referenced as `/dev/sda` but as `/dev/xvda`.

So you should *at least* edit 
`/etc/fstab`:

`# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=631e4952-2bc1-4949-9b25-68409e453ca9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`

(the UUID might have changed)

and the

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

`echo   'Loading Linux 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-kali1-amd64 **root=/dev/sda1** ro single initrd=/install/initrd.gz
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-kali1-amd64`

files